# Rails cannot generate (Windows)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I keep encountering a bug when I execute "rails generate". Below is the error message I receive. I am using Rails 4.0.4 and ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24) [x64-mingw32]

> C:\Users\Phil\Sites\simple_cms>rails generate
>   C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.15/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `requir
>   e': 126: The specified module could not be found.   - C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/ge
>   ms/2.0.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.0.0/mysql2-0.3.15/mysql2/mysql2.so (LoadError)
>    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.15/lib/mysql2.rb
>   :8:in`'
>           from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.0.rc2/lib/bundl
>   er/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
>           from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.0.rc2/lib/bundl
>   er/runtime.rb:76:in`block (2 levels) in require'
>           from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.0.rc2/lib/bundl
>   er/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
>           from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.0.rc2/lib/bundl
>   er/runtime.rb:72:in`block in require'
>           from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.0.rc2/lib/bundl
>   er/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
>           from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.0.rc2/lib/bundl
>   er/runtime.rb:61:in`require'
>           from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.0.rc2/lib/bundl
>   er.rb:132:in `require'
>           from C:/Users/Phil/Sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7:in`'
>           from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/co
>   mmands.rb:43:in `require'
>           from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/co
>   mmands.rb:43:in`'
>           from bin/rails:4:in `require'
>           from bin/rails:4:in`'

C:\Users\Phil\Sites\simple_cms>rails -v
Rails 4.0.4

C:\Users\Phil\Sites\simple_cms>ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24) [x64-mingw32]

Comment: You need to give the specific error message for anyone to be able to help you. Also helpful would be including relevant details about software versions.

Comment: I posted the specific error message/software versions. Thanks!

Comment: I think the mysql2 gem is installed/configured incorrectly. I believe getting that to compile correctly on windows is a bit involved, but there are some guides out there that should help.